# Resizing of new window to the previous window size in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I hava a login button in my first window,which when clicked opens a new window. If my first window is minimised and login button is clicked, then new window opens in maximum size. I want the new window to open in previous login window size(minimised size). How to do this in wpf

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the properties `Width` and `Height` of the Window class to get the size of the previous window just before closing it. And then apply it to your new window.

Keep in mind that your question in not very detailed so i might have misunderstood something, and the solution may vary if you're using pages for example.

Some code : in *Window1.xaml.cs*

```
public partial class Window1: Window
{
    public static double HeightWindow ;
    public static double WidthtWindow;

    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void closing()
    {
        HeightWindow = this.Height;
        WidthWindow = this.Width;
    }
}
```

Use this in any method to get the Height and Width of the window.
I know it's not very detailed but it's a start.
After this you need to pass your variables to your next window (i use static variables here but there are ohter ways i think) and set them like shown : *Window2.xaml.cs*

```
public partial class Window2: Window
{
    public Window2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Height = Window1.HeightWindow ; 
        this.Width = Window1.WidthWindow;
    }
}
```

Hopefully this should do what you want to achieve.

Comment: There are two windows and its not a page. Can you show the code to do it?

Comment: I'll do my best

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will check it and let you know

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Still my 2nd window opens in full screen. I get the width, height of the 1st window in Window_sizechanged function and set the height,width property of window1 in Main function.

Comment: Hey ! First : try tu use breakpoints to see if you get the right height and the right width in your function, ([How to debug](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2019). Look at the parts talking about breakpoints, and remember to advance line per line with f10)

Comment: Sry it's working but sometimes the position of the window is changing. How to show the 2nd window in the same position?

Comment: Use the same techniques as with the `Height` and `Width` but with `Left` and `Top` properties ! :)
(I didn't tested thoses but it should work)

Answer (score 0):

if you name your login window via its Uid attribute, you can then use this to locate the window in the App.Current.Windows collection, then you can capture its width and height and apply the settings when opening the new window

```
foreach (Window window in App.Current.Windows)
{
    if (window.Uid == your_login_window_uid)
    {
        requiredHeight = window.Height;
        requiredWidth = window.Width;
    }
}

secondWindowsViewModel.Width = requiredWidth;
secondWindowsViewModel.Height = requiredHeight;
```

you can set the Uid in the xaml file for your window:

```
 <UserControl Uid="Login">
```

or depending on how you create your window, you can set it during creation:

```
secondWindowsViewModel.Uid = "Login";
```

Comment: There is no uid for my window.

Comment: you can set the UID in the xaml